# Create directory on Android R

Tags: android, android-11

I would like to create a "RawMeasurement" directory in my phone in the same place as Music, Document, Picture... under Android R

I tested with lower api versions, it works, but under android R, impossible.

I think the problem comes from `Environement.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

I've been looking for other methods, but without results.

Ideas? 
thank you in advance

```
public void save(){

    String state;
    state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        File Dir  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),"RawMeasurement");
        if(!Dir.exists()) {
            Dir.mkdirs();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"new folder",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        File file = new File(Dir,"RawMeasurements"+currentDateAndTime+".txt");
        String message = "bla bla bla  " ;
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(message.getBytes());
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"message saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logError("error");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"echec",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: He means the Android version R

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getContext(),"new folder.... ` How often did you see that toast? Check the return value of mkdir()!

Comment: I see the toast when I change the path, but if I save 2 times in a row, I don't see it the second time, so it finds the folder (that I don't see).

Answer (score 2):

Apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage in Android 11. You can create folders inside public directories. For example in Documents folder.

```
final File dir;
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "//MyApp");
} else {
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath()
            + "//MyApp");
}

if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdir();
```

Comment: This solution does not work as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated for Android 11, and will return `null` every single time.

Comment: This is totally wrong. I used this code and changed targetedSdk to 30 and my app crashes. You should use getExternalFilesDir() or getFilesDir().

Comment: Perfectly working solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The permission system since android R has changed a bit, see [Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage) in official documentation for more information.

I used `externalMediaDirs.first()` for my own project but this will place the files in `Android/Media/com.example/`

Comment: it's the same, but on my pixel, i can't access to Android/data/Myapp/com....

Comment: It's not in Android/data but Android/media

Comment: when i open my Android folder, i have nothing, no sub-folder, since I download Android R

Comment: Are you opening the Android folder in root or in let's say the home directory /sdcard/

Comment: i am in the directory /storage/emulated/0/ it's where i found all the application and media directory

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create a "RawMeasurement" directory in my phone in the same place as Music, Document, Picture... under Android R

Sorry, but that is not really supported. You can request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, at which point you could do what you want. My guess is that Google will ban your app from the Play Store unless you can provide a really good justification for that permission.

What Google wants you to do is use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let the user decide where on the user's device that your app should put the user's raw measurements. You can then create a sub-tree (directory) under the user-chosen location, and you can put your content into that sub-tree.

Answer (score 1):

**Create Folder in Android 11+**

- Get permission
  I have created two methods first we will check if the app has permission
  Method name:-isPermissionGranted();
  if the permission is not granted then we will ask the permission by calling this method
  Method name:-askPermissionForStorage();
- Create Folder
  `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Create Your Folder");`
  `file.mkdir();`

**Here is the Two Methods**

```
private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
    } else {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}

private void askPermissionForStorage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, 1);
    }
}
```